# Issue updating Tableview with Swift 2

Tags: swift2

I have a TableView which presents blog posts.  I want to update the tableview when new posts are detected so that a new post appears as the first row in the table.  For some reason the post keeps appearing as the last row in the tableview.  The DataSource of the table view is an array of searchResult objects (each representing a post).

```
   if newPost == true {
                searchResults.insert(searchResult, atIndex: 0)
                print(searchResults[0].articleID)
            } else {
            searchResults.append(searchResult)
                print(searchResults[0].articleID)
            }
        }

    tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Has `newPost` ever been set to true? ;-)

Comment: @vadian that was it.  I was setting it to true but then inadvertently setting back to false.  Thanks!